# Ocean modifier automatically makes time field purple and I cannot keyframe it

Tags: animation, modifiers, keyframes, ocean-simulation

I am trying to loop an ocean modifier [following this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHNlnT3iE9E), but whenever I duplicate the ocean modifier the time field automatically turns purple and I cannot keyframe it.

I have also tried making an entirely new ocean modifier instead of duplicating it, and it also starts with the time field purple.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190761/what-do-various-property-highlight-color-overlays-mean

Answer (score 0):

Purple color means there is a driver. You should be able to delete the driver. Or better, modify it and try the world of drivers. It's amazing.