# *sims 4* object(s) used moved in viewport don't show up in same position when image is rendered

Tags: rendering, objects, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I’m fairly new to blender and I’ve read a few posts on here that are similar but they’re not really helping me fix my problem. I’ll attach images, but in viewport my sims/objects are positioned how they need to be for the pose I’m using but when I render the image the sim on the right has shifted and no matter what I try the rendered image and how it looks in viewport don’t match up. (pls let me know if any other information is needed)
[image]

Comment: Do they have location keyframes on them? Do they have some kind of modifier placing them somewhere which is enabled in either viewport or render and disabled in the other? Or how are they posed, with an armature and maybe they have some stored poses/positions on the bones...? A simple screenshot doesn't really show any information on the objects and how they placed there to determine where the problem lies...

Comment: Where do I go to see of there are any location key frames and/or modifiers or find any stored poses/positions on the bones? The only thing I've ever moved around and really explored before today have just been lights and cameras, my understanding of blender at this point is very basic. If it helps, I can link the youtube video(s) I watched that helped me get to the step I'm at now

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190761/what-do-various-property-highlight-color-overlays-mean/

Comment: ^^^ this comment helped solve everything, thank you so much!!!