# Audio Keyframes - can't change volume

Tags: keyframes, audio

[image]I'm trying to do audio mixing in Blender Video Editor.  I add a keyframe on the Audio track and then set the Volume.  But it immediately gets set back to 1.0.  What am I missing?

Comment: Once you've entered the value, press i (or unclick and reclick on the diamond on the irght of the value) otherwise it will go back to the existing keyframe

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190761/what-do-various-property-highlight-color-overlays-mean