# purple format keys

Tags: modeling

I have a character and I want to use the format keys to change some parts of the character but they are purple and I can't change them. When I have to change a message appears saying: cant edit driven number value, see driver editor for the driver setup. How do I change this?

Comment: A Purple field means that it has a driver attached to it so it can't be changed manually. If you right-click on the field there should be an 'Edit Driver'  and a 'Delete Single Driver' entry. If you know what the driver is for you can delete or edit it, but proceed with caution!

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190761/what-do-various-property-highlight-color-overlays-mean